# strange behavior when getting env var in container

Tags: django, docker, environment-variables, python-poetry

I need to get an env var from an docker container. This build is triggered with a docker compose file and I passed also the env variables with `env_file`. When I login to the container with

`docker exec -it conatinerName bash`

I can echo the variable and get correct output. Even when I trigger

`docker exec -it containerName echo $DEBUG`

inside the poetry environment, I get the correct answer.
When I trigger this command from a terminal session without acitvated environment I get nothing.

For me its very confusing, because I thought my docker container has nothing to do with my poetry environment. I just want to get the env var($DEBUG) from inside the container undependend the location I trigger this command.

Comment: I'd guess the `$DEBUG` string is getting expanded by the shell on your host, before the `docker exec` command runs.  (Do you need a debugging tool like this; can you get this value a different way?)

Comment: good point. Do you know another way to get the value of thix env var? I'm writing a backup tool andwant to store the instance status in the backup file name.

Comment: but still it doesnt make sense why its working from the dev envrionment

Comment: Dont really understand why it worked from my dev environment and not from other sessions. But I found a really good article about this topic. You can user `printenv` to get env var from containers. https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-get-environment-variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Apparently then you have set `$DEBUG` to the desired value, and your command is equivalent to just `echo $DEBUG` (missing quotes and all)